# Listagg in query having aliases

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by, database-administration

I have 99 columns in a query. Most of the columns are having `case` statement so they have aliases. I have to use `listagg` in one such column.
Do I need to put `group by`in remaining 98 columns? How can I do group by when column has aliases because we can not use aliases in `group by`? Is `listagg` possible without using `group by`?

Comment: Some sample data and desired results would really help.  If you want to use `listagg()` you want to use aggregation, so why would `group by` be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

`Listagg` is an aggregate function, so you can't use it without `GROUP BY`. Because it processes before the aliases, you must have also realized that you can't reference the aliases within the `Listagg` statement itself. What you CAN do though is use a common table expression (CTE) to format all your data like you want it and then use the `listagg` on that.

```
WITH temp_view AS ( SELECT … ) //Put your aliased statements in here
SELECT field1, field2, listagg(...) AS field3 
FROM temp_view GROUP BY field1, field2
```

The next part of your question is yes, you will have to use GROUP BY for all fields you select. BUT, if those 99 fields aren't all unique values to the primary key in your table, you can use another CTE to `listagg` only the data that the function needs and then rejoin it back on your main query.

This is a general run down, can't help much more without specifics.

Answer (score 0):

If you could switch to a CTE (I don't see a reason why not), then things get somewhat simpler as you wouldn't have to use all those `CASE`s in the `GROUP BY` clause (yes, you have to use it; no, you can't avoid it).

For example:

```
with temp as
  -- this mimics your current query
  (select ename, 
          case when deptno = 10 then 'abc'
               else 'xyz'
          end dept,
          case when job = 'clerk' then 'cl'
               else 'not cl'
          end job
   from emp
  )
select listagg(ename, ',') within group (order by ename) ename, 
       dept,
       job
from temp
group by dept, job;     --> this! Instead of using CASEs here, use their aliases
```